# object parameters type definition in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am passing a component some props. One of this is a function that doesn't return anything. I have to pass two an object as parameter comosed by two booleans. How do I specify that those parameters are booleans?

```
const MyComponent: React.FC<{
  onChange: ({ isFoo1, isFoo2 }) => void;
}> = ({ onChange }) => {
    const [isFoo1, setIsFoo1] = useState<boolean>(false);
    const [isFoo2, setIsFoo2] = useState<boolean>(false);
  
    /*
    * stuff...
    */

    useEffect({
      onChange({isFoo1, isFoo2})// <----- Type error
    },[isFoo1, isFoo2])
}
```

The typerror has code 2345 and it appears because on `onChange` definition I haven't specified the type of the two parameters.. How can I do that?

Comment: @AlekseyL. That's a syntax error; you can't type parameters with destructuring syntax. (well not a syntax error but it doesn't do what you think it does)

Comment: Right, missing the param itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use destructuring in the type of the `onChange` function. Instead, just use a normal object parameter and type it as you would an object:

```
onChange: (obj: {isFoo1: boolean, isFoo2: boolean}) => void;
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBODCALAhmA5gUwFwwBQgCMArHAbwEsIAxEEARhwNoBsNUAaGSmkAJkZZswAXwCUMALwA+GADcQ5ACaS846TFLCA3ACgdoSLG606KgGbJmEDLoPQu1Wr3OXruhCnQZcFR-U7GfGK6QA)